# PHP sessions acting weird, current object appears in _session

Tags: php, session

I have the following code:

```
<?php


session_start();

class Cinstaller {

    function CInstaller() {
        $this->templates["x"] = "";
    }

    function DoEvents() {

        if ($_GET["x"]) {
            $_SESSION["install"]  = $_GET;
        }       
    }
}

$install = new CInstaller();
$install->DoEvents();

print_r($_SESSION);

?>
```

On a certain server ( first time when i see something like this ) Php 5.2.17, running as CGI/FastCGI, it acts werid.

When i run test.php?x=y I get the following dump:

```
Array
(
[install] => Array
    (
        [x] => y
    )
)
```

When I go back and I run test.php without any other parameters I get the following:

```
Array
(
[install] => Cinstaller Object
    (
        [templates] => Array
            (
                [x] => 
            )

    )
)
```

How the heck the string variable "install" from session turned into the object from current file ?

Comment: Are you getting different results on the same server with passing different values into the session variable?

Comment: There may be something wrong with your apache server as I checked your code works perfectly and it's giving correct output even If I passed other than `y` values..!

Comment: When I did `var_dump($install);` So I got the result as : `object(Cinstaller)#1 (1) {
  ["templates"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["x"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}`

Comment: What you said in your questions more likely says in a way that your `$_SESSION['install'] = $install;` and then after when you do a `var_dump($_SESSION);` so you will perfectly get what you are getting now...!

Comment: I'm getting this results only on one server. on many other servers it works fine. I suspect there is something wrong with the php, but i have no ideea what to look for.

Comment: I checked your code..There is nothing wrong with your code..!

Comment: You are right, somehow it happens this "$_SESSION['install'] = $install;" but there isn't such thing in that code.

Comment: Variable and Sessions are two different things,there values can't come together by itself without assigning them to each other..!`

Comment: @Turn your php file into text file at your host and I will check it then..!

Comment: Do you have a localhost server,if you do have one so try to run the script at your localhost server and then check if you are getting the same output..! & If you don't have one so try to install **XAMPP**

Comment: On my linux server works fine, on windows XAMP works fine, already tested in a couple other locations. Only on that site i get that output.

Comment: So you do know now that there is something wrong with the site Apache Server..! Report back to your Site Hosting Company..i am sure they will fix it..!

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'll do that. I thought there might be something i'm not aware of :)

Comment: Sure..I will take a look if there is something but I also don't think so that if you will be able to fix it if it needs some changes to do to apache server files as assuming that you may be using Shared Hosting only you will be able to do that if you have root access to VPS Server..!

Comment: @One more try you should do...Try to change the name of your variable `$install` to something else and also change your session name from `$_SESSION['$install'];` to something else then check it..!

Comment: Let me know if that fixes your problem..!

Comment: That was the fix i did before i posted the question here on stack. But i was curious to see if there is something else i dont know. :)

Comment: Ok..! To consider this question solved I posted an answer and so it will be better if you move forward with the question and mark the answer as accepted and consider this question solved..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note :** OK..! Seems like you may be having some sort of other problem but as you said that changing names of variable and session solved your Problem so in order to consider this question solved..! Here I am going to post the same answer..!

**Solution :** 
You should change your Variable and Session names to fix this problem there may be some sort of conflict at your server with use of same name for variable & Sessions..!

Answer (score 0):

If you do:

```
$_SESSION["install"]  = $_GET;
```

You will put on "install" session all content that you got by $_GET and the value of session will be an Array().

If you want jut the value of parameter "x" that was sent using GET method, try this:

```
$_SESSION["install"]  = $_GET["x"];
```

And only the value of the "x" parameter will be in the session. Also, filter the value that you get by url:

```
$_SESSION["install"]  = filter_var($_GET["x"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```